# Eliminating certain Django Session Calls

Tags: python, django, session

I was wondering if I could eliminate django session calls for specific views.  For example, if I have a password reset form I don't want a call to the DB to check for a session or not.  Thanks!

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but if you are worried about session performance, cut out the middle man and use memcached.  Then pretty much never worry about calls to the session.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to using memcached as opposed to using the DB for sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are lazily loaded: if you don't use the session during a request, Django won't load it.

This includes request.user: if you access it, it accesses the session to find the user.  (It loads lazily, too--if you don't access request.user, it won't access the session, either.)

So, figure out what's accessing the session and eliminate it--and if you can't, at least you'll know why the session is being pulled in.

Comment: Do you know of a way to check for session calls without using something like django-logging?  That's what I'm using for checking sql calls right now and I don't know if the session call is for django-logging or for the actual app.  I eliminated the session call but it still seems to be querying.

Comment: If you don't mind temporary hacking Django source (which I generally find inevitable), edit django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase._get_session and make it dump a backtrace when it calls load().  That'll quickly tell you who's triggering session loads.